# Thread-safe cloning of network weights in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, thread-safety, tensorflow

I have two neural networks, NN1 and NN2, inside the same Tensorflow graph. I need to update the weights of NN2 with the weights of NN1. For that I execute `session.run([w1_nn2.assign(w1_nn1), w2_nn2.assign(w2_nn1), ...])`, where `wi_nnj` are the weights. Are all these assignments executed as an atomic operation?

If that is not the case (as I suspect), calling these assignments in one Python thread while calling `apply_gradients()` on NN1 in another thread would not be safe, right? So which would be the simplest way to do this in a thread-safe manner?

Comment: I think I know the answer to my own question. Since I use Python, and due to how multithreading works in Python, the `apply_gradients` done by one thread will never be executed at the same time as the variables assignment done by the other thread, right? This is so even though Tensorflow might launch several threads to execute the `apply_gradients` and the assignment, since the Python code will wait until any Tensorflow operation finishes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not atomic. If your variable is GB's in size, the operation can take several seconds, so it's weird to default to such large op being atomic. Also, sometimes it's useful to allow several threads to update the same variable simultaneously, as done in [Hogwild](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1zsvEhrTMAhVLxGMKHaYEC90QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eecs.berkeley.edu%2F~brecht%2Fpapers%2FhogwildTR.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE9XrK7aEEQxMC2XkWxXrfyC90y2A&sig2=j_ceFQaxr2Rz-Vu_Jt5Llg&bvm=bv.121070826,d.cGc)

There's a parameter `use_locking` in various variable update ops that protect from simulatanous update from multiple threads, such as for variable `assign` op [here](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#326)

```
 def assign(self, value, use_locking=False):
    """Assigns a new value to the variable.
    This is essentially a shortcut for `assign(self, value)`.
    Args:
      value: A `Tensor`. The new value for this variable.
      use_locking: If `True`, use locking during the assignment.
```

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. It makes sense. Indeed, the context for my question is the paper [Asynchronous Methods for Deep Reinforcement Learning](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783) where Hogwild is used. Still, it might be that I do not completely understand how Hogwild works, but would not be a problem if one thread updates the parameters of the shared network (NN1) while another thread is copying those parameters to its local net (NN2)? If that happens, after the update, NN2 may contain a mix of both new parameters (i.e., updated with the gradient) and old ones.

Comment: I guess that's not a problem under some conditions, Hogwild paper has some more details on what those "conditions" are